# Pointers in C, C++

Tags: c, pointers

Are these two equivalent?

```
int a=10;
int *p=a; 

AND

int a=10;
int *p;
p=&a;
```

Does p hold address of a in both the cases!?

Comment: The first [doesn't compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/7123518ea71f5fb41265aa2555510721) (at least in C++).

Comment: The first sets the value of `p` to the value of `a`. The second sets the value of `p` to the address of `a`.

Comment: In the first example you are assigning p to point to memory address 10 which is probably property of the OS.

Comment: Why don't you just make two pointers, one for each, and print the values of both? Here's the [result](http://liveworkspace.org/code/781f7db2c4f00463ca6d4d2c990b8e61), which is obviously different.

Comment: In the first you have to alloc a int before "*p = a".

Comment: It doesn't compile in C++! OK. But I had learned in some book that both are equivalent at least in C. Or is it compiler dependent?! Please clarify!

Comment: @StalinSubramaniam, You need an explicit cast in C++ for it to compile.

Comment: It will compile in C, but C lets you do anything. Once you run it, bad things will happen usually.

Comment: @chris: Ya it gets compiled after explicit cast but shows "0xa" as output instead of address!

Comment: @StalinSubramaniam That is ten in hex. Which is what you assigned it to point to.

Comment: @StalinSubramaniam, That is an address. As shown in my above link (4th comment of the question), both pointers point to different addresses.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag since this isn't valid C++ (there exists no implicit conversion from `int` to `int*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case

```
int a=10;
int *p=a;
```

The value contained in the variable a is put into the variable p.  So the value of the variable p is 10.

In the second case

```
int a=10;
int *p;
p=&a;
```

The value in the variable a is 10 and the value in the variable p is the address of a.

In the first case even though the variable p is declared as a pointer to an int the value being put into the variable p is the value of the variable a, a value of 10.  In the second case you are putting the address of the variable a into the variable p.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, the value of `a` is copied into `p` (which stores an address), so `p` points to the address 10.

In the second case, `p` points to the address of `a`.

There is a third case :

```
int a = 10;
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 10;
```

In this case, the value of `a` is copied into the address pointed by `p` (reserved by `malloc()`)

Comment: and in the first case, using or dereferencing `p` on any common OS is almost guaranteed to segfault.

Comment: Yes, doing this is not recommended.

Comment: actually assigning a particular low memory value to a pointer like this might be used with embedded systems using some kind of a memory mapped I/O.

Comment: @RichardChambers Note "on any common OS". Most memory-related bets are off when you're on embedded hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Only the second case is technically correct. In the first case, you assign the *value* of of `a` to `p˙ so you assign an integer to a pointer - it might work, but it does not have to.

In the second case, you correctly assign the address of `a` to `p`, i. e. an `int *` to an `int` variable - that's fine.

Note that even if a variable is declared as a pointer, the compiler won't automatically take the address of the expression on the right side (because in some cases it simply doesn't make sense, for example with a pointer literal...)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int *p=a; 
}
```

Then compile:

```
> g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
```

So not valid C++ because a is not a pointer.
C being a little more lax on type information will allow this. But you get literally what you ask for. The value of `p` is the valud of `a` (10). So `p` is a pointer to address 10 (whether that is a valid address or not is implementation defined).

The second version is valid in both languages.
Because you take the address of `a` and thus the type is correct for assignment to `p`. The result is that `p` points at `a`.

Comment: First case is dangerous. its pointing to a memory location 10. == garbage value could even lead to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The First Case in Incorrect as the pointer should have some address to point to and then the value should go to that address. In the First case the value goes to the an unpointed address Hence an error.

In the Second case the pointer starts pointing at the variable's address in the start. Hence it points to the address containing the value which is correct.